# Passing Arguments from powershell script to python script

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, command-line-arguments

So, what I'm trying to do here is to get from the context menu arguments to pass into my python script. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

This code is my Powershell Script

```
$pythonCode | Out-File -FilePath $scriptPython -Encoding UTF8

# Crear un acceso directo en el menu contextual para archivos ZIP
$rootKey = "HKCU:\Software\Classes\CompressedFolder\shell\RunPythonScript"
$commandKey = "$rootKey\command"

# Crear la clave del menu contextual
New-Item -Path $rootKey -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path $rootKey -Name '(default)' -Value 'JPTest'

# Establecer el comando que se ejecutara
#New-Item -Path $commandKey -Force
#Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value "cmd /C `""C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe`" `"$scriptPython`" `%1`""

# Establecer el comando que se ejecutará y redirigir la salida a un archivo de texto
New-Item -Path $commandKey -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value 'cmd /C "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" "$scriptPython" %1'
```

And the way I'm trying to use it on my Python script is the following:

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: 'Path/to/IronPython/ipy.exe' CompilerTool.py <ZipFilename> <ZipFilePath")
    sys.exit(1)


source_zip_file = sys.argv[1]
folder_name = os.path.basename(source_zip_file)
directory_of_zip = os.path.dirname(source_zip_file)
```

The way I intend the python code to get the arguments from the PowerShell script is the following #"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" CompilerTool.py "name of the folder.zip" "path to the folder"

The problem is that I believe the way I'm retrieving the arguments is wrong. I believe this line of code

`Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value 'cmd /C "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" "$scriptPython" %1'`

Isn't working with how I'm managing the arguments in python.

Comment: And what is your question/problem? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I modified the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: "Isn't working" is as vague as it gets, you're gonna have to be more specific. What _happens_? Do you see any error messages? What happens if you change the python script to print the arguments before validating or change the expected argument count to 3 or 4?

Comment: What happens once I right clicked and select "JPTest" on the context Menu, is that nothing happens . It briefly opens a CMD terminal and then it closes almost instantaneously. I haven't tried putting any print statements before, but I tried writing the output of my command on a .txt file and what I received was: 

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try changing `cmd /C` to `cmd /K` so the command prompt stays open, might reveal the problem (I'd test in conjunction with printing the raw arguments one by one in the python script). My best guess is that you'll need an extra layer of escaped quoting, eg. `%1` -> `"%1"` or `\"%1\"`. @mklement0 you're pretty well-versed in command line parsing, any bets? :)

Comment: The thing is, I'm still getting the error: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Shall I change or add single Quotes to the code I'm putting on the registry editor?

Comment: Try escaping the program path too, eg. `"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe"` -> `\"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe\"` or `""C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe""`

Comment: I tried both ways, both showed an error, first I tried this one:
Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value 'cmd /K "\C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe\" "$scriptPython" %1' and I got: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

And with the second one:
Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value 'cmd /K ""C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe"" "$scriptPython" %1' I got: '"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe"" "$scriptPython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: show it in question - it will be more readable.